# How does this for loop work on the following string?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have been working through Automate the Boring Stuff by Al Sweighart. I'm struggling with understanding the code below:

**INPUT**

```
message = 'It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.'
count = {}

for character in message:
 count.setdefault(character, 0)
 count[character] = count[character] + 1

print(count)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'I': 1, 't': 6, ' ': 13, 'w': 2, 'a': 4, 's': 3, 'b': 1, 'r': 5, 'i': 6, 'g': 2, 'h': 3, 'c': 3, 'o': 2, 'l': 3, 'd': 3, 'y': 1, 'n': 4, 'A': 1, 'p': 1, ',': 1, 'e': 5, 'k': 2, '.': 1}
```

**QUESTION**

Since it does not matter what the variable in a for loop is called (ie character can be changed to x, pie etc) how does the code know to run the loop through each character in the string?

Comment: It is a property of `strings` that iterating over them produces each character in turn. As you say, it is not a matter of naming variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about the variable's name, it's about the *object* this variable points to. The implementation of the loop in the Python virtual machine knows how to iterate over objects based on their types.

Iterating over `something` is implemented as iterating over `iter(something)`, which in turn is the same as iterating over [`something.__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__). Different classes implement their own versions of `__iter__`, so that loops work correctly.

`str.__iter__` iterates over the individual characters of a string, `list.__iter__` - over the list's elements and so on.

---

You could create your own object and iterate over it:

```
class MyClass:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([1,2,3,4])

my_object = MyClass()
for x in my_object:
    print(x)
```

This will print the numbers from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

A string is an array in python. So, it means that when you loop on a string, you loop on each character; in your case, you set what has been read to `character`.

Then, setdefault maps character to 0 if character is not yet in the dict. The rest looks quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are sequences of chars : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq. Therefore, the `for c in m:` line iterate on every elements of the `m` sequence, i.e. on every character of the string